# SQL - Using Cursor & Implement statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_employee IS
Emp_name trkemployee.name#%TYPE,
Emp_ID trkemployee.E#%TYPE,

CURSOR c1;
IS
select e.e#, e.name from trkemployee e where e# IN (select e# from trkdriver intersect select e# from trkmechanic);
IN 
(select e# from trkdriver intersect select e# from trkmechanic);
BEGIN
OPEN c1();

LOOP

END LOOP;
close c1;
END;
/
```

Above is my PL/SQL code.. what i am trying to achieve is to list all the employee who work as driver & mechanic at same time..

i execute the sql statement alone at the terminal and the output is as followed..

```
SQL> select e.e#, e.name from trkemployee e where e# IN (select e# from trkdriver intersect select e# from trkmechanic);

        E# NAME
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        14 Andrew R. Smith
```

But i wanna do it in PL/SQL and do a DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT(result);

I Know to check for multiple record , i need use cursor. assuming in future there will be more than 1 row return, how should i change my pl/sql and when i load procedure, terminal say got compilation error.

Below is my 3 tables..

```
SQL> desc trkdriver;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 E#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(12)
 L#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 STATUS                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> desc trkmechanic;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 E#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(12)
 L#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 STATUS                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 EXPERIENCE                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)


SQL> desc trkemployee;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 E#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(12)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 DOB                                                DATE
 ADDRESS                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(300)
 HIREDATE                                  NOT NULL DATE
```

Comment: @Mat , i am using oracle

Comment: Then don't put the MySQL tag (and certainly not C++) on your questions please.

Comment: Do you actually have a field named `E#`? Not that it's bad, but it's... uncommon.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes i have a field name E#

Answer (score 2):

You have the whole `IN (select ....` part twice in your code. I think that's what the compilation error is about.

I also think 2 `in`s will be faster, because Oracle may use the indexes better:

```
select 
  e.e#, 
  e.name 
from 
  trkemployee e 
where 
  e# IN (select e# from trkdriver)
  and e# in (select e# from trkmechanic);
```

Tip: If using cursors like this, you need to add a lot of exception handling to prevent cursors staying open in case of an error. The `for` loop makes looping through cursors easier and safer:

```
for r in C loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.e#);
end loop;
```

Also, I can imaging that `e#` is a field name that may cause trouble in PL/SQL. I'm not sure about that, but if you get compilation errors, that may be the case. I'd rather go for a more common name like 'EmployeeNr`.

[edit]

Your code has a couple of errors. First, there's a `;` after `cursor C1` that shouldn't be there. Also, there is no code inside your loop, which isn't allowed in PL/SQL. If you need to test it, but you haven't code code yet, you can type `null;` for 'a piece of code that does nothing. Like:

```
loop
  null;
end loop;
```

Your whole code could look like this. This one actually compiles and should get you going to finish it with what else you may need.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE verify_employee IS

  CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT
      E.E#,
      E.name
    FROM
      trkemployee E
    WHERE
      E# IN (SELECT E# FROM trkdriver)
      AND E# IN (SELECT E# FROM trkmechanic);

BEGIN
  -- R becomes an alias for each row. You can access the fields
  -- of the rows inside the loop
  FOR R IN C1 LOOP
    -- Output each Emplyee number.
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(R.E# || ', ' || r.name);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution and help. but how do i integrate your code into my PL/SQL, sorry for asking. its seems like asking more when you already give me a clear answer, but i still very unfamiliar with pl/sql

Comment: No prob. Apparently you have a couple of syntax errors in your procedure. If you got a good tool (I use PL/SQL developer myself) you should be able to see where and what errors you've got. I've found a fews that I described in an addition to my answer. I've also added a procedure that compiles, which should get you going.

Comment: B.t.w. Using `E#` as a fieldname turns out not to be a problem at all, even in PL/SQL.